# HTML5 offline cache (application cache) limit and offline Video/Audio behavior for Android tablet

Tags: html5-appcache

I am validating the HTML5 application cache limit and Video/Audio behavior for Android tablets and below are my observations
Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0 P3100
Android OS: 4.1.2

1. **Android browser:** 
   The maximum caching limit is 378 MB. The limit is per domain.
   The Video (used mp4 format file) & Audio (used mp3 format file) elements gets cached but it does not get played in the offline mode. It only gets played in the online mode.
2. **Chrome browser (27.0):** 
   The maximum caching limit is 940 MB. The limit is per domain and in one time 35 MB of data can be cached. Meaning need to cache data in chunks of 35 MB and for this purpose we can either update the same manifest file with the new data or we can make use of multiple manifest files
   The Video (used mp4 format file) & Audio (used mp3 format file) elements gets cached but it does not get played in the offline mode. It only gets played in the online mode.

Based on the information read on the internet I was under impression Android do support unlimited HTML5 offline caching and hence would like to confirm my above observations.

If anyone has observed any other behavior than which is mentioned above then please share the same.